# Investments as an NRI

Tags: india, investing

I would like to gain clarification in regards to my investments made as a resident and also as a NRI (Non-Resident Indian).

1. The investment done in mutual fund during the tenure being an resident was continued even after residence status had changed to NRI. This investment has been stopped and the new investments in mutual funds as NRI have been started.
2. Insurance policies (Life, medical, accident) were all taken when had been a working in India. Even though the status has changed the documents of theses polices still have not been updated. Kindly let me know the steps to be taken in regards to this point.
3. Bank accounts were opened during the period of working in India. After the status was changed to NRI. The payments for the policies(as in point 2) still get deducted from theses accounts. Need to know the procedure to change the status of the insurance policies without affecting the ULIPS. One of the polices is a investment done in the name of my son.
4. Other accounts being held as joint with my wife are they taxable, as my wife is a IT payee in India.

Comment: Which country are you living in now?

Comment: Welcome to PF&M! This question seems quite broad. You might want to split it up into specific questions that are independently answerable.

Answer (score 1):

> The investment done in mutual fund during the tenure being an resident was continued even after residence status had changed to NRI.

An NRI [Except from Canada and US] can invest in Mutual Funds in India

> Insurance policies

Most policies are global and do not affect the residency status. As long as you are paying premium on time you should be fine. You can inform your status and new residential address.

> Other accounts being held as joint with my wife are they taxable, as my wife is a IT payee in India.

Any income earned in India is taxable.